# gdal incorrectly quoted string literal Oracle OCI

Tags: oracle, gdal

I updated to gdal version 2.
Now i get to error if i want get data from my Oracle Database.

```
ogrinfo -ro OCI:database/passwd -sql "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename"
```

The Error i get is: Incorrectly quoted string literal.
with the old gdal version 1.xx it works correctly
I think the problem is the oci.dll at the gdalplugins. Has anybody some idea

After waiting a little bit i get the error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
```

It doesn't know why, because with the old gdal version it had worked

Answer (score 0):

SQL quoting is strict in 2.x that 1.x, see:

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT#L123